# Simulate ARIMA model in R using same starting values as original time series?

Tags: r, arima

I have built an ARIMA model in R with the "forecast" package's `auto.arima()` function. I want to simulate the ARIMA model with the same starting values as the original time series. For example, if my original time series has values from time 0 to time 2000, I want the ARIMA model to simulate the same time period (0 to 2000). If the ARIMA model is ARIMA(5,0,1), I want the values from time 0 to time 4 to be retained in the ARIMA model and the model simulates from that point on using those first 5 points.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: You may be interested in [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/127441/initialize-arp-process-by-using-arima-sim), which gives an example for an AR model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(forecast)
fit <- auto.arima(wineind)
plot(wineind)
lines(simulate(fit,future=FALSE), col='red')
```

[image]